# Non-uniformly continuous functions and Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If *f*: A $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ for A $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$, and {$a_n$} is Cauchy, how do I prove that *f* ($a_n$) is also Cauchy? 
I know how to do this when *f* is uniformly continuous, but what if all I am given is that A is closed, and *f* is continuous?

Comment: $A$ is closed and $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Yes, I should have clarified that, I apologize

Comment: If $A$ is closed and $f$ is continuous, it follows that $f$ is bounded and so $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is $f$ continuous. Pick $\epsilon > 0$ and by continuity produce $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\vert x - y \vert < \delta \implies \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \epsilon.$$
Since $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy, there exists some $N$ such that
$$n,m > N \implies \vert a_n - a_m \vert < \delta.$$
Therefore
$$n,m > N \implies \vert f(a_n) - f(a_m) \vert < \epsilon,$$
thus $\{f(a_n)\}$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

That $f$ is uniformly continuous if $A$ is closed and bounded (compact) follows from the result that $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition: a sufficient pick of constant here would be $K = \sup_{x_0, x_1 \in A} \frac{|f(x_1) - f(x_0)|}{|x_1 - x_0|}$, $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{A}$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Comment: I see, thank you very much.